# Merton's Portfolio Problem Monte Carlo Simulation

Tags: portfolio-optimization, monte-carlo

I am currently studying Merton's Problem Portfolio from the slides here:
[https://stanford.edu/~ashlearn/RLForFinanceBook/MertonPortfolio.pdf](https://stanford.edu/%7Eashlearn/RLForFinanceBook/MertonPortfolio.pdf)

Where they stated the optimal solution are:
[image]

I tried to do a simple Monte Carlo simulation using the optimal solutions and the SDE:

[image]

and compare it with the analytical formula for V* at time 0 as below

```
def Sim(mu, r, sigma, gamma, rho, k, X0, T, N, M):  # N = number of timestep, M = sample size
dt = T / N
sqrt_dt = sqrt(dt)
normals = sqrt_dt * np.random.standard_normal(size=(N, M))  # generate a NxM matrix of (0,dt) normals
epsilon = k ** (1 / gamma)

pi_star = (mu - r) / (gamma * sigma * sigma)
alpha_factor = (((mu - r) ** 2) / (2 * sigma * sigma * gamma)) + r
alpha = (rho - (1 - gamma) * alpha_factor) / gamma

def f(t):
    if alpha != 0.:
        f_num = 1 + (alpha * epsilon - 1) * exp(-(alpha * (T - t)))
        f = f_num / alpha
    else:
        f = T - t + epsilon
    return f

W = np.ones(M) * W0

for n in range(N):
    c_star = W / f(n * dt)
    W += ((r + (mu - r) * pi_star) * W - c_star) * dt + sigma * pi_star * W * normals[n]

u_star = k * np.sign(W) * (np.abs(W) ** (1 - gamma)) / (1 - gamma)  # terminal wealth
V0_star_MC = np.mean(u_star)
V0_star = (f(0) ** gamma) * (X0 ** (1 - gamma)) / (1 - gamma)
print(V0_star_MC)
print(V0_star)
```

However, I got a big difference between the Monte Carlo result and the analytical formula. I checked all the numbers and constants by hand and they seem to work fine. Is there anything wrong with the way I simulate the SDE and recompute C* in each loop? I also assume the terminal wealth to be calculated at each path is the boundary condition:
[image]

Is this correct? Thanks a lot!

I used the following parameters for my simulation:

```
mu = 0.15
r = 0.05
sigma = 0.2
gamma = 0.8
k = 0.8
rho = 0.1
W0 = 100
T = 1
N = 1000
M = 10000
```